# Drop Down value mapping into anthore Drop Down in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown and in this dropdown I have two field `Randomslab` and `standard style`.

When I select `Randomslab` then I need only one value in the next  `dropdown(300*300)`.

When I select `standard style` then I need all value in next `dropdown(300x300,300x600,600x600)`.

But currently i am getting all value for both the fields, I need first value for first field and all for other in next dropdown. How can I achieve this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a size:</p>
<select ng-model="selectedtype" ng-options="x for (x, y) in type">
     </select>
<select ng-model="selectedsize" ng-options="x for (x, y) in size">
</select>


<h2>length: {{selectedsize.length}}</h2>
<h2>bredth: {{selectedsize.bredth}}</h2>


</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.size = {
                         "300x300" : {length : "300",bredth : "300"},
                         "300x600" : {length: "300", bredth : "600"},
                         "600x600" : {length : "600", bredth : "600"}
                    }
         $scope.type = {
                         "Randomslab":{},
                         "standard tyle":{}
                    }           
                    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slightly modifiy your model data, in order to populate the second dropdown accordingly.

You'll probably have to add some work around on `selectedtype` change, in order to select a default value for the selected size and avoid this annoying blank field.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a size:</p>
<select ng-model="selectedtype" ng-options="x for (x, y) in type">
     </select>
<select ng-model="selectedsize" ng-options="x for (x, y) in selectedtype">
</select>


<h2>length: {{selectedsize.length}}</h2>
<h2>bredth: {{selectedsize.bredth}}</h2>


</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.type = {
         "Randomslab":{ 
            "300x300" : {length : "300",bredth : "300"}
         },
         "standard tyle":{
            "300x300" : {length : "300",bredth : "300"},
            "300x600" : {length: "300", bredth : "600"},
            "600x600" : {length : "600", bredth : "600"}
         }
    };           
                    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```